# Visual Studio 2012 Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I use Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 8 PC. I had no problems when installing VS2012.

When I'm working on a ASP.NET c# project I usually use the option "See in the explorer" instead debug the project. This gives me the ability to change code behind.

Sometimes after build and press F5 to reload the page I get some errors. This doesn't happend always, but very often.

> The errors are: CS2021, CVT1100, CS1566...
>   "Can't find file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\617be439\61539075\App_GlobalResources.iuxkzxdi.0.cs'"
>
> Always the "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root" is the problem. Sometimes it says can't find file others it says access denied.

Visual Studio works but is horrible to keep pressing F5 until the error goes away.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm also seeing this after upgrading (clean install) to Windows 8 yesterday. Extremely annoying.

Comment: I'm still having this problem. Next week I'm changing to VS 2013 and see how it works

Comment: I actually have VS2013 ... Happens probably once or twice every hour while I'm coding. Another save of the file in VS and/or multiple refreshes and the system figures out it should recompile (or whatever it does to fix it)

Answer (score 3):

Run VS2012 as Administrator. Local account by default have restriction accessing the build/temporary locations and will throw such errors. You'll have similar problems when trying to publish websites.

Therefore, It is easier to set VS 2012 once, and check the box in properties to "Run program as administrator" to allow it run always as "Administrator".

Comment: Thanks for helping, but after setting everything to run as administrator I'm having the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone who can help? I can't fix it. Thanks.

Comment: can you confirm the user with which you are running VS as? which group he is in? If it has rights etc. Error states some sort of permissions issue. Have you tried clean the project first and then build it? Does error go away? Is it a website or web application project type?

Comment: I'm logged as an Administrator user. Also I've set "run as administrator" to the VS 2012 exe. Yes, I have cleaned and recompiled again. This is a web app and I have tried 4.0 and 4.5 frameworks...still the same issue

Comment: It looks like it has something with the ASP.NET folders, sometimes the access is denied, others can't find the file...